# Conversion of the units BeV (US) and GeV (UN)

Tags: units, unit-conversion, conventions

What is the difference in the definition of a billion electron volts in United states (US) and United Nations (UN)?

When the US people say billion, do they mean $10^{12}$ or $10^9$?

Comment: Nobody has used BeV in a serious context in decades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the US, 1 billion = $10^9$.

The difference is between the [Long and short scales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_scale). The US uses the short scale, where a billion is $10^9$. In the long scale, a billion is $10^{12}$.

In the short scale, every term after a million (billion, trillion, etc.) is 1,000 times bigger than the previous one. So, million = $10^6$, billion = $10^9$, trillion = $10^{12}$.

In the long scale, every term after a million is 1,000,000 times bigger. So, million is again $10^6$, but billion = $10^{12}$, and trillion = $10^{18}$.

---

If you just use SI prefixes, though, those are the same everywhere. $10^9 eV$ is one GeV, whereas $10^{12} eV$ is one TeV.

Comment: milliard=$10^{9}$

Comment: @Non-standard: yes, milliard is a term used to describe one thousand millions in the long scale. Where I live, if you said milliard they would look at you as if you were crazy (unless they knew French, in which case they would understand exactly what you meant :) )

Comment: your's definition is complete but this could be origin of thousands problems when you try to translate a physics lecture!!
how can i release what was the goals of authors!?

Comment: @Non-standardmodel Hmmm, that is tricky! The wikipedia article I linked has a list of countries that use each scale, so if you know the nationality of your author, you can make a pretty educated guess. Also, you know that your author is going to consistently use only one system, so if you ever see terms like `milliard` or `billiard`, you know (s)he is using the long-scale. Likewise, if (s)he ever says "one billion eV (or 1 GeV)", you know (s)he is using the short scale.